# Drawing in 3D with LibGDX

Tags: 3d, libgdx, lwjgl

Is there any way to simply draw in 3D, just like you would draw with ShapeRenderer or SpriteBatch? All I want is to draw circles that are in x.y.z coordinates, so some circles are far away from view and some are closer. Also I would like to be able to rotate these circles.

Comment: Do you mean SPHERES or circles? They aren't the same thing. LibGDX team is working on a 3D api. Not sure how far they are with that.

Comment: Well circles was just an example, any shape would do, as long as they have z coordinate depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to draw in 3D is to wait until LibGDX has [implemented their 3D functionality](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=7020).

Otherwise, you can simulate the effect in 2D. Basically, you [change the scale of the object](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47038/simulate-movement-towards-the-screen-in-a-2d-world) to represent its movement along the Z-axis. Rotating would only be with respect to the current 2D perspective.

Comment: So they are working on 3D functionality that would work in same way as ShapeRenderer but also in 3D?

Comment: I don't know how they plan to make it work. You'd have to ask them.